# ZendFramework - Why is $this->fetchRow() failing?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Why this database query failing? in my CentOS.

Error/Exception:

```
"Notice: Undefined variable: table in /var/www/html/-manager/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 37 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAdapter() on a non-object in /var/www/html/-manager/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 37 Warning: Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0
```

Disk space?:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_demo-lv_root
                       50G   47G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   47M  413M  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_demo-lv_home
                      170G  200M  161G   1% /home
```

Calling as:

```
    $rows = new Application_Model_Clients();  // PASS
    $dbsession = $rows->give_sessions("test"); // FAILS
```

Stocked as:

```
mysql> select username,password from sh_operator;
+----------+----------+
| username | password |
+----------+----------+
| test     | 1234567  |
+----------+----------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 


<?php

class Application_Model_Clients extends Zend_Db_Table {

  protected $_name = 'web145-mydb.sh_operator';

  public function addRecord($post) {
    $encrypted = mt_rand();
    $value = array(
        'email'       => $post->email,
    );
    return $this->insert($value);
  }

  public function search($zip) {
    $result = $this->fetchRow("zip =" . $zip);
    return $result->toArray();
  }

  public function give_sessions($input) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($input); // PASS test
    echo "alive 0 "; // PASS
    $result = $this->fetchRow("username ='" . $input . "'");
    echo "alive 1 "; // fails
    exit;
    return $result->toArray();
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: Please add your error/exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a database name with "-", you may need to use backticks to assign it to the adaptor correctly.

```
   protected $_name = '`web145-mydb`.sh_operator';
```

The exception shows that you do not have disk space left. Clear up some space, that should solve the issue.

Comment: @janez00: same problem still with both answers.

Comment: Have you enabled error_reporting and exceptions in your application.ini?

Comment: yes it shows "Notice: Undefined variable: table in /var/www/html/-manager/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 37 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAdapter() on a non-object in /var/www/html/-manager/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 37 Warning: Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: line 37 is: $dbsession = $rows->give_sessions($user);

Comment: Okay, thats another issue. Check the disk space on your server first

Comment: `# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_demo-lv_root
                       50G   47G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   47M  413M  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_demo-lv_home
                      170G  200M  161G   1% /home
`

Comment: The / is full. Looks like that is why the queries cannot be executed. Also, look at the failed to write session error. Its also because php is not able to write to session save path since disk is full. Clearing some space should solve the issues

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18665/discussion-between-janenz00-and-yumyumyum)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your sql for `give_sessions()` is likely to end up with to many quotes `"username ='" . "test" . "'"`.

You might consider making it easy on yourself and just use the provided [select()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building) object syntax which will handle the quoting for you. [fetchRow()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html#zend.db.table.row.read) will just make a [select()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building) if you don't.

```
public function give_sessions($input) {
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->where('username = ?', $input);
    $result = $this->fetchRow($select);
    return $result->toArray();
  }
```

Using select() also allows for a lot of flexibility in how you structure your queries.

You may wish to test your current adapter config with some code in a controller action like:

```
$table = new Application_Model_Clients();
Zend_Debug::dump($table->getAdapter()->listTables(), 'Adapter Table List');
```

which will echo out an array of the tables that the adapter has access to.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3964576  - still fails same way in line 4 `$select = $this->select();`

Comment: is the actual name of your table `sh_operator` or is it `web145-mydb.sh_operator`. the second looks more like a host and a table name.

Comment: `Zend_Debug::dump($table->getAdapter()->listTables(), 'Adapter Table List');` while using this fails "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Comment: then you have problem with your database adapter. Start there first.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3964948 - database access with same username password works manually, and that is what i set also in application.ini. But still same.